# Custom python function not working

Tags: python, function, syntax-error

I was learning Python from Codecademy.

**There's a question:**

Write a function, `shut_down`, that takes one parameter (you can use anything you like; in this case, we'd use s for string). The `shut_down` function should return `'Shutting down...'` when it gets `'Yes'`, `'yes'`, or `'YES'` as an argument, and `'Shutdown aborted!'` when it gets `'No'`, `'no'`, or `'NO'`.

**In response to this, I wrote this:**

```
def shut_down(n):
    p=n.lower()
    if p=="yes":
        return "Shutting down..."
    elif p=="no":
        return "Shutdown aborted!"
```

**But, when I try to run it, the following error occurs:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined*
```

Please help me...is there some kind of mistake in my code?

Comment: I'm guessing that you put `yes` instead of `"yes"` in the first line of your file, but you didn't show it so hard to say for sure... Advice: READ what the compiler says :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is kinda hard to tell exactly what is going on since you didn't include line 1 (the line of the error).  However, judging by my personal experience, I think your problem is one of two things:

1) You are on Python 2.x and using `input` when you should be using `raw_input`:

```
>>> input()
yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
>>> raw_input()
yes
'yes'
>>>
```

2) On the first line you have `yes` when you should have `'yes'`:

```
>>> yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
>>> 'yes'
'yes'
>>>
```

In both cases (and any I missed), you are treating "yes" as a defined variable instead of a string.

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-c7VZg/4/1?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096 Check this out... i tried everything but it's not working...

Answer (score 1):

The above code works fine. May be the problem is, while you are calling the function, you have used `shut_down(yes)` instead of `shut_down('yes')`

Comment: actually there is a app that automatically test the code... so when i submitted it shows an error.